# balls as Foelner sets

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

This is essentially equivalent to  [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43964/folner-sequences-of-amenable-groups-of-exponential-growth)  question by Simon Thomas. Let $G=\langle X\rangle$ be a finitely generated group, $b_n$ be the number of elements in the ball of radius $n$ in the Cayley graph.

1) Is it possible that the limit $\lim \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ does not exist?

2) Suppose that for every constant $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $n$ such that $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\le 1+\epsilon$. Does it imply that $\lim \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=1$?

Note that the condition of 2) implies that the group is amenable and one can take balls as Foelner sets (which would contradict a statement in de la Harpe's book).

**Update:**  The first part has been asked and answered already before (see Andreas' answer below). About 2): here is a stronger question. Suppose that an amenable group $G$ is finitely presented. Are there constants $\epsilon>0, N$ depending only on the lengths of the defining relations so that if $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\le 1+\epsilon$ *for some* $n>N$, then the limit above exists and is equal to 1? This is similar to a statement proved by Shalom and  Tao about polynomial growth, but for groups of subexponential growth.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: A post on meta.MO would probably drum up the necessary votes.

Comment: Ah, yes, your new question is indeed presumably *not* a duplicate!  I don't know if I can undo my vote, but I'll try...

Answer (score 3):

Both questions have been asked before. The answer to Question 1 is negative, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36126/on-the-size-of-balls-in-cayley-graphs/36132#36132).
Question 2 appeared just some hours ago [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43964/folner-sequences-of-amenable-groups-of-exponential-growth).

Comment: Yes, I did not know that (the first question). Thanks!

Comment: @Andreas: Question 2 is not exactly the same as Simon's. It might be possible that if for *some* $n$ $b_{n+1}/b_n<1+\epsilon$  for some very small (universal constant, depending on the presentation) $\epsilon$, then the limit exists and is equal to 1. That is why I formulated it this way.  The answer could be different for finitely presented and infinitely presented groups.

Comment: I have updated the question. 